# Variance of the maximum of two independent exponential random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent exponential random variables with rate $\lambda$. I am trying to find the variance of $X_{(2)}$. I found the Expected value of $X_{(2)}$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the meaning of $X_{(2)}$ ?

Comment: Why cannot you apply the method you used to find the expected value, to the second moment? What is this method, already?

Comment: @callculus A complicated way to say $\max(X_1,X_2)$.

Comment: $X_{(k)}$ is the $k$-th minimum of the sample $\{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n \} $.

Comment: ´@Did I have browsed the internet and found the meaning of it. But thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W$ be the maximum of the $X_i$. If $w\gt 0$, we have $W\le w$ if and only if $X_1\le w$ and $X_2\le w$. The probability of this is $(1-e^{-\lambda w})^2$.

So now we have the cdf of $W$. Differentiating, we find that  $W$ has density $2\lambda e^{-\lambda w}(1-e^{-\lambda w})$, which is 
$$2\lambda (e^{-\lambda w}-e^{-2\lambda w}).$$
You probably found $E(W)$ using the above density function. For the variance, we use the fact that $\text{Var}(W)=E(W^2)-(E(W))^2$.

So it remains to find $E(W^2)$. This is equal to 
$$\int_0^\infty w^2 2\lambda (e^{-\lambda w}-e^{-2\lambda w})\,dw.\tag{1}$$

One can use integration by parts, or recycle known results about the exponential. If we recall that the exponential has variance $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$, we can see that $E(X_i^2)=\frac{2}{\lambda^2}$. Thus 
$$\int_0^\infty 2w^2\lambda e^{-\lambda w}\,dw=\frac{4}{\lambda^2}.$$
Similarly,
$$\int_0^\infty 2w^2\lambda e^{-2\lambda w}\,dw=\frac{2}{(2\lambda)^2}.$$
So now we know $E(W^2)$, and using your known value for $E(W)$ we can find the variance of $W$.

Comment: The PDF is twice what you wrote.

Comment: Thanks, I approached the same way, except that I got a wrong pdf, that's where I got lost.

Comment: @Did: Thanks for noting the missing $2$.

Comment: @Sanwar: You are welcome. Too bad they did not ask about the minimum, it would have involved less typing!

Comment: The OP specifies that the mean is $\lambda$. You are using the rate as $\lambda$ - wrong parameterisation.

Comment: @wolfies: Thank you, I did not notice since $\lambda$ is so commonly used as the parameter, as in $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$. Have put a note at the beginning.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. wolfies was right, it supposed to be rate, not mean. However the question is corrected.

Comment: @Sanwar: I removed the edit, since it turned out that my (careless) reading was the intended one.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that $X_{i} \sim \mathcal{E}(1/\lambda)$, by using the memoryless property of the exponential r.v. and dividing the maximum into two independent increments, you get the following sum 
$$
X_{(2)} = X_{(1)} + (X_{(2)} - X_{(1)}),
$$ 
where the first summand is the $\min\{X_1, X_2\}$ and the second is just  $\mathcal{E}(1/\lambda)$ r.v., so
$$
Var(X_{(2)} ) = \frac{\lambda^2}{2^2} + \lambda^2
$$

Comment: Also wrong parameterisation ... OP defines $\lambda$ as mean